# cv2.imread results in artifacts and jagged edges around a transparent png

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to open a transparent png using

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("images/262.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


cv2.imshow('Original', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But there are imperfections around the edges. The edges are jagged and sometimes artifacts appear around them. When I open the same image using Preview or a different program it looks perfectly fine, nice and smooth. What's causing this? I'm trying to use the image to make a canny map and the jagged edges also show up on it.

The left image on the screenshot is the image opened with cv2.imread, and the right is the same image opened with Preview.

[image]
The original 262.png image:
[image: 262.png]

Comment: How are you displaying the image on the left loaded with imread? Perhaps how you're displaying it is showing the image in a lower resolution, irrespective of the fact the data itself is storing the original resolution.

Comment: Please edit your post and the original `262.png` image file. Please add the missing lines of code that displays the image.

Comment: The image seems to have an alpha channel (transparency), which is ignored by cv2.imread

Comment: I added the missing code. As far as I know, passing `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` into `cv2.imread("images/262.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` should keep the alpha channel, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Yeah, the alpha channel is kept by imread, but not used by imshow

Comment: It is an issue, since cv2.imread() will ignore it and you will see black. How are you viewing / displaying/ saving the file such that it now shows black. What you are seeing is aliasing from turning off the anti-aliasing in the 8-bit alpha channel.

Comment: imread is NOT the issue, imshow is. imshow does not handle the alpha channel in any way. it shows the colors that would have been "shown" as transparent (invisible) by other display methods. that information is there, you just don't see it ordinarily. there is no aliasing. that is literally how transparent data works. transparent pixels are allowed to have arbitrary colors. the background could have been entirely pink and that would have been legal. -- anyway, OP, are you just asking about unexpected things you see in the imshow window, or do you have an actual issue with actual processing?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't fully understand how the alpha channel worked with imshow, this makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I learned from the comments that this is the normal behaviour of the imshow function. I assumed before that imshow would handle the alpha channel if I used `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` but now I see that this is not the case.